# Laravel multi relationship

Tags: php, html, laravel, vue.js

I am working on chat application in laravel/vue and in this app I have users where each user have several rooms each room has at least 2 user in it and several messages I am trying to make relation or query to get all the rooms for each users and the messages in them

```
Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email')->unique();
        $table->enum('status',['active','busy','Do Not Disturb']);
        $table->timestamp('email_verified_at')->nullable();
        $table->string('image')->default('user0.jpg');
        $table->string('password');
        $table->rememberToken();
        $table->timestamps();
    });

Schema::create('rooms', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->string('room_unique');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
Schema::create('messages', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->enum('type',['text','image','link']);
        $table->string('content');
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->foreignId('room_id')->constrained()->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is good. I would just take out the foriegn key `user_id` from rooms and access user's room through their messages. Hence, `messages` will be like a pivot table making the relationship between users and rooms many to many.

Hence to access the rooms of a user I would

`$rooms = User::find(1)->rooms()->get();`

To access users in a room

`$users = Room::find(1)->users()->get();`

To display messages of a user per room would be like accessing pivot table. Hence

```
$user = User::find(1);

foreach ($user->rooms as $rooms) {
    echo $rooms->pivot->content;
}
```

So, this is many to many relationship and message is the pivot table. I will stick with the [documentation for more details.](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many)

Comment: If we have many rooms for a user, we'll have a foreach of $user->rooms as $room,  and a foreach of $room->messages as $message, or group message of each user by room_id.

Comment: Yes, we can have many rooms per user. That is why I queried one user and get all the rooms the user is in. Then you continue with the for loop as you suggested. Also, there are multiple messages in each room, but they all belong to a user, not the room. Hence you get the messages using `$rooms->pivot->content` or `$users->pivot->content`

Comment: We should already know, here it is surely a question of having all the messages of the users of the room, or just the messages of the active user in the room,
and since it's not a HasManyThrough to have all messages of the user Through rooms, You should already know, here it is surely a question of having all the messages of the users of the room, and not just the messages of the user in question,
and since it's not a HasManyThrough, we're going to get messages from all users. it seems to me that we're going to get messages from all users in the room, and i think is the correct way, or what?

Answer (score 0):

The best solution i have found is to make complex relation like this
//relations

```
public function message() 
{
    return $this->hasMany(messages::class)->take(1);
}

public function friends()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(User::class, 'friends', 'user_id', 'friend_id');
}

public function rooms()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Room::class,'user_room','user_id','room_id');
}

public static function getInit()
{
    //get room of auth user
    $rooms =   DB::table('user_room')->where('user_id',Auth::id())->select('room_id')->get()->toArray();

    //flatten the array
    $roomArray = array_column(json_decode(json_encode($rooms), true),'room_id');

    //get users friends and rooms belong to auth user with the last message 
    $user = User::with(array('friends.rooms' => function($query) use ($roomArray){
                $query->whereIn('rooms.id',$roomArray);
            },'friends.rooms.messages' => function($query) {
                $query->orderBy('created_at','Desc');
            }))->whereId(Auth::id())->get()->toArray();
    return $user;
}
```

in getinit I just use this relation after each other like (friends.rooms)

laravel will use friends relation then each result will use rooms relation on it in my case i just need to pick rooms that user and friend have so i limited the relation by using where in rooms belong to the auth user like if we say the auth user has rooms 2,3,4 and his friend has 3,1,5 so the room relation will only return the union of auth user rooms and friend rooms in our case it's 3 then i return messages in each room but for design purpose i just need the last message for each room so i limit my relation message to take 1 and in getinit order them by created date desc